# How to make typeless interface for my repositories in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a couple of repositories and want them to Implement a interface but the implementing
methods should be the same - select, insert, etc. But the implementing method would change. 
There are a couple of alternatives you could make, what's one of the better ones?

```
 interface IRepository
    {
        List<T> Select();
        int Insert(T); 
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `interface IRepository<T>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create interface and that interface can be implement in your class.

```
  public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(object id);
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);         
    }
```

you can use **repository pattern** and **Unit of Work Patterns** in here as well.

```
 public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
    {
        private DbContext context = null;
        private DbSet<T> dbSet = null;

        public Repository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

        #region IRepository

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet;
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            this.context.SaveChanges();
        }

       #endregion
    }
```

in this case you can pass any type of object. 
for more details and examples check [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)